# How to embed remote image in ImageMagick

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to do a simple thumbnail generation from an image that isn't located on my server using the iMagick wrapper for ImageMagick. For some reason, the following code will not display anything when called:

```
<?php
   $image = new Imagick("http://kunaki.com/ProductImage.ASP?T=I&ST=FO&PID=PX003Y9EDJ");
   $image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
   header( "Content-Type: image/jpg" );
   echo $image;
?>
```

I've also tried using `http://kunaki.com/ProductImage.ASP?T=I&ST=FO&PID=PX003Y9EDJ.jpg` to no avail.

Based on comments below, I've attempted this as well with no results, but am not sure if the syntax is correct.

```
<?php
   $kunaki_image = file_get_contents("http://kunaki.com/ProductImage.ASP?T=I&ST=FO&PID=PX003Y9EDJ");
   $name = tempnam("/tmp", "kunaki");
   $final = file_put_contents($name, $kunaki_image);
   $image = new Imagick($final);
   $image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
   header( "Content-Type: image/jpg" );
   echo $image;
?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: do you get this error? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/jmvarela/public_html/ihateyourjacket.com/game/image.php on line 2

Comment: no, I just don't get any result at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick's constructor is [badly documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-construct.php) so I can't tell for sure, but maybe Imagick can't deal with remote file paths.

Try fetching it separately e.g. using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or `curl`. Store it locally under a temporary name, and pass it that.

Comment: @Trufa meaning what exactly? What happens?

Comment: I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/jmvarela/public_html/ihateyourjacket.com/game/image.php on line 2 with either one...

Comment: @Trufa that error has nothing to do with whether the file is fetched remotely or locally. It is a sign of a syntax error on line 2.

Comment: i tried `file_get_contents()` , nothing. How would I approach storing locally, then removing when the page is closed?

Comment: @Dave get data using `file_get_contents()`, create temporary file name using `tempnam()`, save to file using `file_put_contents()`

Comment: Updated my question, can you check it out?

Comment: @Dave turn error reporting on: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, it will show you what goes wrong

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/home/davekiss/public_html/ÿØÿà': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2403' in /home/davekiss/public_html/thumbnail-generator.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /home/davekiss/public_html/thumbnail-generator.php(4): Imagick->__construct('??????JFIF?????...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/davekiss/public_html/thumbnail-generator.php on line 4

Comment: that worked! how does `file_put_contents()` play into the `$name` variable that is passed into the IMagick class?

Comment: nevermind, I see what is happening now. Thanks a bunch! Wish I didn't have to store locally, but this will do.

Answer (score 5):

I had to do the same thing with Youtube... you need to pass the file path to ImageMagic, not the file_put_contents instance.

```
<?php
   $kunaki_image = file_get_contents("http://kunaki.com/ProductImage.ASP?T=I&ST=FO&PID=PX003Y9EDJ");
   $name = tempnam("/tmp", "kunaki");
   file_put_contents($name, $kunaki_image);
   $image = new Imagick($name);
   $image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
   header( "Content-Type: image/jpg" );
   echo $image;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you perfer cUrl,

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$image = new \Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($resp);
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
header( "Content-Type: image/jpg" );
echo $image;
```

Answer (score 1):

a little improvement to avoid writing on the disk:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("http://kunaki.com/ProductImage.ASP?T=I&ST=FO&PID=PX003Y9EDJ", 'rb');
$image = new \Imagick();
$image->readImageFile($handle);
fclose($handle);
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
header( "Content-Type: image/jpg" );
echo $image;
```

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion since it does not create any temp files. If you want it to work with more image formats then jpg change the header line to: header('Content-Type: image/'.$image->getImageFormat());